# Can't run conda with the bash script

Tags: bash, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I wrote the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate my_env
```

After it a type:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

and I try to run it with:

```
./script.sh
```

but nothing happens.
Ideas?

Comment: Run it in debug mode: `bash -x ./script.sh` and see what happens.

Comment: a lot, but nothing interesting (no errors, no warnings etc). just exports